Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.average' or unsupported use of the function
I am a student in 12th grade doing a small internship for a school, attempting to extract tables from images of attendance sheets, using img2table (version 1.2.11). I have copy pasted this code for experimenting as of now:
from img2table.ocr import TesseractOCR
from img2table.document import Image

# Instantiation of OCR
ocr = TesseractOCR(n_threads=1, lang="eng")

# Instantiation of document, either an image or a PDF
doc = Image('images.png')

# Table extraction
extracted_tables = doc.extract_tables(ocr=ocr, implicit_rows=False, borderless_tables=False, min_confidence=50)

However, this is the error I am currently getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Akeen/Akeen - Main Folder/Akeen python projects/OCR test and research/tablesExtract.py", line 11, in <module>
    extracted_tables = doc.extract_tables(ocr=ocr,
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\document\image.py", line 46, in extract_tables
    extracted_tables = super(Image, self).extract_tables(ocr=ocr,
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\document\base\__init__.py", line 125, in extract_tables      
    from img2table.tables.image import TableImage
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\image.py", line 19, in <module>
    from img2table.tables.processing.borderless_tables import identify_borderless_tables
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\processing\borderless_tables\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from img2table.tables.processing.borderless_tables.layout import segment_image
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\processing\borderless_tables\layout\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from img2table.tables.processing.borderless_tables.layout.rlsa import identify_text_mask
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\processing\borderless_tables\layout\rlsa.py", line 156, in <module>
    def get_text_mask(thresh: np.ndarray, cc_stats_rlsa: np.ndarray, char_length: float) -> np.ndarray:
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\decorators.py", line 218, in wrapper
    disp.compile(sig)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock        
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 819, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 82, in compile
    raise retval
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 92, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 105, in _compile_core
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(self.targetdescr.typing_context,
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 627, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 363, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 425, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 405, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 396, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 332, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock        
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 291, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 264, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 92, in run_pass
    typemap, return_type, calltypes = type_inference_stage(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 70, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate(raise_errors=raise_errors)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeinfer.py", line 1071, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.average' or unsupported use of the function.

File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\processing\borderless_tables\layout\rlsa.py", line 167: 
def get_text_mask(thresh: np.ndarray, cc_stats_rlsa: np.ndarray, char_length: float) -> np.ndarray:
    <source elided>
    # Get average height
    Hm = np.average(cc_stats_rlsa[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT], weights=cc_stats_rlsa[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
    ^

During: typing of get attribute at C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\processing\borderless_tables\layout\rlsa.py (167)

File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\processing\borderless_tables\layout\rlsa.py", line 167: 
def get_text_mask(thresh: np.ndarray, cc_stats_rlsa: np.ndarray, char_length: float) -> np.ndarray:
    <source elided>
    # Get average height
    Hm = np.average(cc_stats_rlsa[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT], weights=cc_stats_rlsa[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
    ^

I have tried to bypass the 'numpy.average' function by manually calculating the weighted average using this code:
def calculate_weighted_average(data, weights):
    total_weighted_sum = sum(d * w for d, w in zip(data, weights))
    total_weight = sum(weights)
    if total_weight == 0:
        return 0  # Avoid division by zero
    return total_weighted_sum / total_weight

But, the error still persists.
Even after reading img2table's docs, I still don't understand what steps to take to fix this error. Any help is appreciated.
Edit:
The above code snippet was used like this:
from img2table import document

# Function to calculate the weighted average manually
def calculate_weighted_average(data, weights):
    total_weighted_sum = sum(d * w for d, w in zip(data, weights))
    total_weight = sum(weights)
    if total_weight == 0:
        return 0  # Avoid division by zero
    return total_weighted_sum / total_weight

# Path to the image containing the table
image_path = "images.png"

# Create a Document object and extract tables
doc = document.Image(image_path)
extracted_tables = doc.extract_tables(ocr=True, implicit_rows=True, borderless_tables=False, min_confidence=50)

# Process the extracted tables
for table in extracted_tables:
    # Access table properties and data
    num_rows = table.num_rows
    num_columns = table.num_columns
    table_data = table.data
    # Process the table data as needed
    print(f"Table with {num_rows} rows and {num_columns} columns:")
    for row in table_data:
        # Replace numpy.average with calculate_weighted_average function
        weighted_average = calculate_weighted_average(row['data'], row['weights'])
        print(f"Weighted average: {weighted_average}")

I have also updated numba, but it still doesn't seem to work.
Edit 2:
Updated NumPy, now it has prompted a new error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Akeen/Akeen - Main Folder/Akeen python projects/OCR test and research/tablesExtract.py", line 11, in <module>
    extracted_tables = doc.extract_tables(ocr=ocr,
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\document\image.py", line 46, in extract_tables
    extracted_tables = super(Image, self).extract_tables(ocr=ocr,
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\document\base\__init__.py", line 125, in extract_tables
    from img2table.tables.image import TableImage
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\image.py", line 11, in <module>
    from img2table.tables.metrics import compute_img_metrics
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\img2table\tables\metrics.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numba import njit, prange
    from numba.core import types, errors
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\types\__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    long_ = _make_signed(np.long)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 320, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'

I have tried various combinations of versions of NumPy and Numba, but either one of the errors constantly keep popping up.

Hard to tell, since error is in that img2table code (that I've never heard of before now). But apparently img2table internal code uses np.average in a numba compiled function. And numba says it doesn't support np.average. Which it does, on my computer. So, I would say, either it is a version problem (your numba version maybe too old). But maybe it is also another error, because numba distinguish functions with argument types; no maybe it only means "I do not support average with this kind of arguments"

Start to update numba (and the rest, while you are at it).

(As for providing a new weighted average: but where did you put that function? Did you edit the img2table internal code to replace their usage of np.average with that function? Because if not, that can't help. And if you did, well, it could work, but that is not sustainable — next time an update will occur, your code would be overwritten)
